$P(X \ge a) \le \frac{E(G(X))}{G(a)}$
Prove that if $G(x) > 0$ is an increasing function of $x$, then for a given random variable
$X$, we have $$P(X \ge a) \le \frac{E(G(X))}{G(a)}.$$
I'm having a hard time with this proof. I'm not really sure how to get it started.
I tried looking for answers to this question on this site already, but I didn't find anything posted about this on math stack exchange. If this has already been answered, then please share the link.

Possible hint: Markov.

Verify that $1_{X\ge a}\cdot G(a)\le G(X)$, etc.

Does $G$ have to be strictly increasing here? I wanted to try using $P(X\ge b) = P(G(X)\ge G(a))$

$1_{X \geq A}*G(A) \leq G(X)$ because $G \geq 0$,
$E$ is increasing, so:
$E(1_{X\geq A}*G(A)) \leq E(G(X))$
By linearity and because $E(1_{X\geq A}) = \displaystyle\sum_{\omega \in \Omega, X(\omega)\geq A} P(\omega) = P(X \geq A)$ , you get:
$G(A) * P(X \geq A) \leq E(G(X)) $

could you please explain the first line, how do we know that its less than $G(X)$

Two cases : if $X<A$ and $X\geq A$. The first one, if $X<A$, then the left side of the equation is zero, while the right is at least 0, because G is positive. For the other case, if $X \geq A$, then the left side is G(A), and the right is G(X), which is bigger than G(A) because $G$ is increasing, and $X\geq A$.

okay, thank you!

but it states that $G(x)>0$, so how can it be at least zero? In the first case, wouldn't the right side be greater than $0$ and we have a strict inequality?

Yes, we would, a strict inequality is stronger than a large, if a strict is true, a large is also true (but not the other way around !). This doesn't affect the proof.

I was initially using this: $P(X≥b)=P(G(X)≥G(a))$, would this work? i had similar steps to your proof, but I wasn't sure if it was okay to use this

That's not true unfortunately. Take G to be the constant function equals to 1. For all a real number, $P(G(X)\geq G(a)) = 1 $, while $P(X \geq b$ is not necessarily equal to one. You can still say something, because the set ${\omega such that X(\omega) \geq a}$ is included in ${\omega such that G(X(\omega)) \geq G(a)}, you've got  $P(G(X)\geq G(a) \geq P(X\geq a). Your equality would be true if G was STRICTLY increasing, which we don't know.

okay, got it, thanks!
